# How do I declare a type where I pick a property from an Interface and make the picked property's properties optional?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

Like in this example, I don't want to pick a property and make the entire thing optional.   But instead, I want to make the picked property's properties optional.

Currently I am solving this problem by explicit writing `{items: Partial<Item>[]}`.

Is there a smarter way?

```typescript
interface Item{
    id: number
    name: string
}

interface User{
    id: number
    name: string

    items: Item[]
}

type UserWithOptionalItemsItself = Pick<User, "id" | "name"> & Partial<Pick<User, "items">>
const x:UserWithOptionalItemsItself = {
    id: 1,
    name: "user name",
    // items is optional.. this is not what I want
}

type UserWithOptionalItems = Pick<User, "id" | "name"> & {items: Partial<Item>[]}
const y:UserWithOptionalItems = {
    id: 1,
    name: "user name",
    // you have to have items, but the properties are optional
    items: [{
        id: 123
    }]
}
```

[TypeScript playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYG8BQz-LAAmAXMiAK4YBG0eBIcGEZAzmFKAOY4C+OOUJFiIUAVVbRcBQqXJVaUevkbM2HbgJnBMrMuggYA2gF0+AsAE8ADuMlQA6joAWAeWthgAe0YAbAxis6JK+MMgAvMgACsAIANYAPBLQADTIAETE6cgAPhmqEOkAfMgAZNFwUJ5wvgkx8Un2aZm6xUU4CD7syAAeJMmOLu6ePjUBQWAhYZHSBMRkAIwpyuRMLBkU9qvM6csyAPT7hLqErMheHt5+AHTXyGDOwGdP5F5gyADuznDvqJ9w4HMOCstmQAycD2GVzGJ0i9USA2aWVy+TWxTKyCwOkMegqVWANQSASKpn4nRA3Us-XsELcl1G-lhmJW82QSxWBTI6U20G2hT2BEOyEsXgoyG+ADcUGAvOK4FLjji0tQKO8HihrFALtBPBAzpUUBcRn4WboyEZZjJ8KyFgAmADMK14Zl4QA)

Answer (score -1):

Here, `id` and `name` are mandatory, where `items` is optional. If not provided, they will return `undefined`.

You can also provide default value to items:

```
interface User{
    id: number
    name: string

    items?: Item[] | undefined
}
```